# Error al intentar cargar datos en base de datos

Tags: php, mvc

estoy empezando con la programacion a objetos en php y el paradigma MVC. quiero hacer un simple form donde me carga tres datos, 2 string y un decimal y al darle clic al boton este es el error que me sale:
Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\tarea\eia\controlador\formulario.controlador.php on line 13
busque en google y en la pagina pero no pude encontrar solucion, estos son los codigos

este es el controlador:

```
<?php

class ControladorFormulario{

    /*alta de productos*/

    static public function ctrRegProductos(){

        if (isset($_POST["producto"])) {

            $tabla = "stock";

            $datos = array("producto" -> $_POST["producto"],
                           "cantidad" -> $_POST["cantidad"],
                           "proveedor" -> $_POST["proveedor"]);

            $respuesta = ModeloFormularios::mdlProductos($tabla, $datos);

            return $respuesta;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

la linea 13 a la que hace referencia el error es:

```
$datos = array("producto" -> $_POST["producto"],
                           "cantidad" -> $_POST["cantidad"],
                           "proveedor" -> $_POST["proveedor"]);
```

y este es el modelo:

```
<?php
require_once 'cnx.php';

class ModeloFormularios{

    /*registro de productos*/

    static public function mdlProductos($tabla, $datos){

        $query = con::cnx() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (producto, cantidad, proveedor) VALUES (:producto, :cantidad, :proveedor)");

        $query -> binParam(":producto", $dato["producto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query -> binParam(":cantidad", $dato["cantidad"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query -> binParam(":proveedor", $dato["proveedor"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if ($query -> execute()) {

            return "ok";
        }else{

            print_r(con::cnx() -> errorInfo());
        }

        $query -> close();

        $query = null;
    }
}
?>
```

alguna ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

Estas utilizando un operador equivocado para arrays  sustituyelo con lo siguiente

```
$datos = [
    "producto" => $_POST["producto"],
    "cantidad" => $_POST["cantidad"],
    "proveedor" => $_POST["proveedor"]
];
```

Ademas al momento de correr tu query, utilizas una variable que no existe

```
// Utilizas $dato cuando debe ser $datos
// No separes con espacio la variable del atributo ->
// Tienes mal escrito binParam, debe ser bindParam
$query->bindParam(":producto", $datos["producto"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Adicionalmente, está usando `$query->binParam(...)` cuando debe ser `$query->bindParam(...)`